# For any element $e$ of an open set $V$ of a covering space, does there exist a sheet $S$ such that $e\in S\subseteq V$

Tags: algebraic-topology, examples-counterexamples, covering-spaces

Let $p:E\rightarrow X$ be a covering map. Let $V$ be any open subset of $E$ and $e$ be any element of $V$. I feel that the following statement must be true:

There exists an evenly covered open subset $U$ of $X$ such that $p^{-1}[U]=\cup_{i\in I} S_i$ ($\{S_i\}_{i\in I}$ are the sheets over $U$) and $e\in S_{i_0}\subseteq V$ for some $i_0\in I$.

I spent some time trying to prove it, but I didn't succeed . I prefer hints more than full answers (if the statement is true).

Thank you

Comment: I hope my edits are correct. If not feel free to revert.

Comment: @DanielRust  did not notice the difference, but it looks OK. Do you have any idea about the question ?

Comment: @DanielRust I think proving the above stateent would be very easy if $E=\mathbb{R}$ and $p:E\rightarrow X$ is $e^{2\pi t i}$, but I didnt succeed for the general case

Comment: I've thought a little on it, and it seems like one of those statements that is intuitively obvious, but is maybe not so easy to prove (if a counterexample does exist I think it would involve some kind of pathological space).

Comment: I'm having some trouble understanding what the issue is? It seems true by definition to me. $p(e)=x\in X$ has a ngbd whose preimage consists of disjoint opens mapped homeomorphically to it (def. of a covering map), and $e$ is in one of them. I must be misunderstanding the question?

Comment: @BenBlum-Smith You're right, I was over-thinking it. I thought that $E$ would need some kind of separation property as you need the points in $p^{-1}(\{p(e)\})$ to have separated neighbourhoods. But this property is fully captured by the fact we have a covering map.

Comment: @DanielRust I still don't see it, could you write an answer that explains all details. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Edited. The objection of the OP was substantial.)

Let $e':=p(e)\in X$. The point $e'$ has an open neighborhood $U'$ which is evenly covered by $p^{-1}(U')\subset E$. Let $S_0$ be the sheet of $p^{-1}(U')$ that contains the point $e$. Then $W:=S_0\cap V$ is an open neighborhood of $e$, and $W':=p(W)\subset U'$ is an open neighborhood of $e'$. This neighborhood is evenly covered by $p^{-1}(W')$, and the sheet of $p^{-1}(W')$ containing $e$ is $W\subset V$.

Comment: why is there a sheet $S_i$ such that $S_i\subseteq V$. This is the place where I couldn't move further

Comment: @Amr: See my (tiny) edit.

Comment: Now my question will become: Why does $U'\subseteq V'$ imply $S_i\subseteq V$ for some $i\in I$ ?

Comment: $p^{-1}[U\cap V']$ is really $p^{-1}[U ]\cap p^{-1} [V']$ which is equal to $p^{-1} [U] \cap p^{-1}[p[V]]$. I agree that there must exist a sheet $S_i$ such that $e\in S_i\subseteq p^{-1}[p[V]]$, but I don't see why we must find a sheet $S_i$ such that $e\in S_i\subseteq V$

Comment: Put differently, I agree about this if $V$ is assumed to be $p$-saturated

Comment: Hello, in case you feel that my objection is not right, but you do not want to waste time in explaining why my objection is wrong , you can just tell me "Your objection is wrong/ does not make sense"  without any further explanation. Thank you anyways

Comment: OK. Thank you. ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

Let $U\subset X$ be an evenly covered neighbourhood of $p(e)$ and let $U_0=U\cap p(V)$. We know that $e\in V$ so $p(e)\in p(V)$ and so $p(e)\in U_0$. Also $U_0\subset U$ and so $U_0$ is also an evenly covered neighbourhood of $p(e)$.

Because $U_0\subset p(V)$ we have that $p^{-1}( U_0)\cap V\neq\emptyset$ and indeed this means that at least one of the sheets of $U_0$ is contained in $V$ and exactly one of these contains $e$. This sheet is equal to $S_i$ for some $i\in I$ by the definition of $p^{-1}(U_0)$ for $U_0$ evenly covered.

Comment: "indeed this means that at least one of the sheets $U_0$ is contained in $V$ and contains $e$" Why ? I agree that one of the sheets must be contained in $p^{-1}[p[V]]$ and contains $e$ but I don't see why what you mentioned is true

Comment: Do you agree ? ${}{}{}{}$ Put differently, I agree about this if $V$ is assumed to be $p$-saturated

Comment: Hello, in case you feel that my objection is not right, but you do not want to waste time in explaining why my objection is wrong , you can just tell me "Your objection is wrong/ does not make sense"  without any further explanation. Thank you anyways

Comment: Ok I agree. For instance if $p\colon S^1\times \{0,1\}\rightarrow S^1$ is the projection map, and if $e=(e^{0\pi i},1)$, $V=S^1\times\{0\}\cup (S^1\setminus \{-1\})\times\{1\}$, then if we choose $U= S^1$, we would get $U_0=S^1$ but the sheet over $U_0$ which contains $e$ is not contained in $V$ and so the above argument does not work.

Comment: Maybe we need to set $U_0=p(S_i\cap V)$ where $S_i$ is the sheet over $U\cap p(V)$ which contains $e$.